# LocalDateTime to RealmInstant conversion

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, realm

Can someone suggest a way to convert a simple `LocalDateTime` into a `RealmInstant`?

I've tried this approach, I mean the value of this converted LocalDate time is not in the same format as the RealmInstant.

Good RealmInstant value (Not the same date/time value as below, but the format is the key here):

```
+054848-03-16T07:54:02.000+00:00
```

Bad Converstion from LocalDateTime to RealmInstant:

```
2022-11-23T22:04:06.000+00:00
```

This is the code that I'm using to convert a LocalDateTime into a RealmInstant:

```
RealmInstant.from(
    epochSeconds = LocalDateTime.of(pickedDate, pickedTime).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC),
    nanosecondAdjustment = LocalDateTime.of(pickedDate, pickedTime).nano
)
```

Comment: Can you add some test data? What's the input and actual vs expected output?

Comment: @user3738870 The input for the "pickedDate" and "pickedTime" is just the current date/time. And the expected result is the same date/time but only in the form of a RealmInstant.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps parsing makes it format differently?

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-11-23T22:04:06")
RealmIstant ri = RealmInstant.from(ldt.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC), ldt.nano)
Date date = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(ri.epochSeconds, ri.nanosecondsOfSecond, ZoneOffset.UTC)
```